# Why does OSX create AppleDouble files on a Samba share, but not on a Windows file share?

Tags: macos, network-shares, samba, freenas

We deployed a FreeNAS server with Samba shares on a network consisting of Windows and OSX clients.

When the OSX clients copy files onto the Samba shares, a lot of [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appledouble) (for example, `._something.jpg`) files will be created. When copying the same files to a file share on a Windows-based server, the files won't be created.

What is special about the Samba share that causes this behavior and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: this may help a little: https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-ntdom/2000-May/012198.html

Comment: after poking around a bit, my **hunch** is that its because EXT4 supports resource forking, whereas NTFS does not.

Comment: @FrankThomas: Sadly, it doesn't. It talks about a specific directory, not the generic `._` files. Either way, using `veto files` to *prevent* the files is counter-productive as pointed out here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7086/how-to-disable-appledouble-files-for-smb

Comment: @FrankThomas NTFS supports resource forking. Alternate Data Streams were added with **precisely** this intention in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X's SMB client will store extended file metadata in named data streams if it determines that the server supports them; if not, it falls back to storing the metadata in AppleDouble ("._") files. See [Apple support article #HT4017](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4017).

A windows server serving from an NTFS volume will support these automatically (they get stored as NTFS alternate data streams). AIUI with a Samba server, you need an extension like [vfs_streams](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_streams_xattr.8.html) or [vfs_streams_depot](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/vfs_streams_depot.8.html), but I'm not sure of the details.